# What is the right way to respond to this Triage review item?

Tags: support, review-queues, triage, specific-audit

I was going through the triage review queue, and I stumbled upon [this review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/32259071):

[image: Triage review]

The system already marked it as possible spam. I was going to put a `Blatantly Off Topic` flag on it, but it is (kind of?) on topic on the basis that it IS about a programming site, although the question itself is off-topic. So in my opinion, this question isn't BLATANTLY off topic, it's just normal off topic. Since I'm not sure (and I don't want to get a flag declined), I went to Meta to get a solution.

The tag is also *clearly* wrong, as React has nothing to do with Haskell, and this isn't even about the language - it's about a site **related to** Haskell.

Also, the asker answered their own question in the comments one and a half months before asking. This is likely an audit, but I'm not sure what the appropriate action to take here would be.

What should I do to answer this triage item?

Comment: (spoiler alert: it's an audit) IIRC most audits end at the top level selection. I believe Flag + Submit would be enough to complete the audit. The system wants you to cast a spam flag there (to match the state of the question)

Comment: @HenryEcker: So I just need to cast a spam flag? Because Flag+Submit doesn't pass the audit, it opens the flag popup asking what kind of flag I want to enter.

Comment: Interesting. That's different that "Share feedback" which [doesn't make you select a follow up action](/q/412271/15497888). I would assume either red-flag would work there either (spam or R/A), but I could be wrong. Spam should definitely work.

Comment: It looks like a moderator marked that question as spam after the user followed it up with [this mess of a question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72801211).  Personally, I'm not sure that it's actually spam.  However, the answer is nonsense, and was posted by someone with a similar name, so it seems they're up to _something_.

Comment: Two questions highlighting the same domain is spammy for sure. Though not sure it makes a good audit in any case.

Comment: As far as the *actual* correct answer, which you should not put in because you will fail the audit...arguably, it's on-topic: it sounds like it's about using a programming tool.  The fact that the tool is a website doesn't necessarily make it off-topic.  I've redeleted the question in a way that will make it not get used as an audit again.

Comment: @RyanM and Henry Ecker: OK, thank you! I'll just hit skip on this triage and continue. Thanks again for your help :)

Comment: NP. I went ahead and completed this audit so it doesn't hang around in queue and end up confusing someone else and as Ryan said it will no longer be chosen for audits moving forward.

Comment: After talking to the other moderator involved, it turns out the question is also a verbatim copy of [this older question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35830625/208273).  So...yeah, it was definitely worthy of being deleted, but not in a way that can be spotted by a reviewer.

Comment: “Also, the asker answered their own question in the comments one and a half months before asking.” - If it’s a comment then it’s not an actual answer, which means the question is unanswered, which is a problem since it will be eligible to be automatically be pruned if it receives enough downvotes (apparently or I am going to guess it’s already deleted)

Comment: the review system needs urgently an overhaul, that question is on topic and has only 1 question, so it is ok,

Comment: Obligatory reminder that there's [no shame in skipping](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252195/6296561)